# Laravel 5.7 undefined variable token in view file when trying to send password reset link

Tags: laravel-5.7

I have made a custom notification for sending password reset link and
custom blade for the mail but I don't know how to pass the token variable into  myPasswordNotification.blade

User.php

```
use App\Notifications\myPasswordResetNotification;

public function sendPasswordResetNotification($token)
{
    $this->notify(new myPasswordResetNotification($token));
}
```

myPasswordResetNotification.php

```
namespace App\Notifications;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;

class myPasswordResetNotification extends Notification
{
use Queueable;
public $token;
/**
 * Create a new notification instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct($token)
{
    $this->token = $token;
}

/**
 * Get the notification's delivery channels.
 *
 * @param  mixed  $notifiable
 * @return array
 */
public function via($notifiable)
{
    return ['mail'];
}

/**
 * Get the mail representation of the notification.
 *
 * @param  mixed  $notifiable
 * @return \Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage
 */
public function toMail($notifiable)
{
   return   new(MailMessage)->markdown('notifications.users.myPasswordNotification');
}

}
```

myPasswordNotification.blade.php

```
@component('mail::button', ['url' => route('password.reset', $token)])
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed the toMail function to this and now it seems to be working.

```
public function toMail($notifiable)
{
    $url = route('password.reset',$this->token);
    return (new MailMessage)->markdown('notifications.users.myPasswordNotification',['url'=> $url]);
}
```

And I changed myPasswordNotification.blade.php to this.

```
@component('mail::button', ['url' => $url])
```